# php recover inputs added with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, dynamic

I did a little form with jQuery, that when a button is clicked, it adds a new input with a name.

The jQuery I add to the page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 2;
    $("span").click(function() {
        $("#add").before("<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type='text' name='name-"+i+"' /></td></tr>");
        $("#numper").val(i);
        i++;
    });
});
```

`$("#numper").val(i)` is an hidden input to know how many times I added an input.

When I check the console and Elements (F12 in Chrome) the fields are added, and the hidden one is changed correctly, but when I try to obtain the values with PHP, it says that the added inputs are undefined.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['numper']; $i++) {
echo $_POST['name-'.$i];}
```

If you can help me to sort this out, I would be very grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put the 'name' attribute in the inputs you add with jquery?

Comment: it's there, of course, gonna edit the post question, forgot to add it in the question

Comment: Can you show the html code?

Comment: absolutely correct, you need to put name attributes, i encountered this problem before, and i solved just like user Lan said

Comment: Please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can get a better understanding of your code.

Comment: if you want i can post different code but the same problem, but it is in cakephp, if you can understand cakephp, then i am willing to post the answer

Comment: More interested in the javascript and html code that you're using, the PHP, like Lan said, looks for the name attribute.

Comment: Well, as you said, here is a http://jsfiddle.net/YrUYS/1/ jsFiddle from the code, the jquery works fine, adding the name that should be, same when I try it in local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if below code helps you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#addbutton').click(function() {
            var i = parseInt($('#numper').val()) + 1;
            $('#table').prepend("<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type='text' name='name-"+i+"' /></td></tr>");
            $('#numper').val(i);
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method='post' action='<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='button' id='addbutton' value='Add new input box' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id='table'>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='name-1' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='hidden' id='numper' name= 'numper' value='1' />
                <input type='submit' value='submit' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
</body>
```

```
<?php
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $_POST['numper']; $i++ ) {
    echo $_POST['name-' . $i] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply approach your requirements in a different way, name all your inputs so PHP reads them as an array like so:

```
<input name="name[]" ..... />
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $index => $input_value) {

   ....

}
```

Comment: it happends the same, not saying undefined, but just the input added with jquery doesn't appear.

Comment: Better use the browser dev tools (i.e. F12 in chrome and firefox) to look at the HTML after you have clicked the add new input button. This definately works as i use it often, so either your inputs are being added outside of the <form> or your javascript is not using the correct name. What is the result if you `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your PHP script, so you can see what is being sent?

Comment: I press F12 (in chrome) and look into the HTML after i clicked the add button, and yes, it's added with the name. also, don't know why, I noticed that the form closes before adding any input, but it available to send the first one that it's static. I add a photo:
http://i79.photobucket.com/albums/j146/IAmTheEvilAngel/jquery.png

1-Choose and loads the page that will show the form.
2-When clicked +Persona, it adds thouse inputs with the name

As i mentioned, I don't know why it shows the form closed, but at least, the firsts inputs are send correctly

Comment: Seems like you accepted an answer, but basically your inputs are outside of the form, so they will not be submitted when the form submits

Comment: just found it, I answered the question, the thing was, that i didn't know, that a form inside a table seems to not work, so I put the form tag outside the table and now works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you have variable i = 2. So, your first input will have a name "name-2".

In PHP, you have for loop with variable $i = 1. So it will try to get $_POST['name-1'].

So, it will give error for undefined.

Comment: i know, I got initiallized a field with "name-1", so that's why i = 2

Answer (score 0):

for the jquery part, you can write this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn1").click(function(){
$("p").append("<input name='whatever' type='text' class='whatever'>");
});


});
```

if you want the php part, then notify me

Comment: it's almost the same, just i needed "before" instead of "append". inputs are added with it's name, but for some reason when submitting or recieving the values doesn't works